# Spaces populating as 0 in the first postion in datastage(v8.5)

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am using a condition in transformer to populate space values if two statements gets satisfied. My derivation is as below:

If (Column1=Column2 And Column3='') Then Column4='' Else Column4(It's incoming value) --> So in this condition column3 is having a datatype of Char(50). So, while executing this condition the output of the condition IF statement is getting satisfied as 0 instead of space. Column4 is also having a datatype of Char(50).

Requirement: Column4 should populate same as column3 value if, IF statement is satisfied or else it should populate it's original value coming from source. I am using datastage(v8.5). Also when writing to peek stage and seeing it is coming as 0. Tried all ways of Space(50), " ", ' ' etc.,

please help out on this. let me know if any details needed.

Note: Column3 is read from a dataset file. Suggest on this or let me know if I miss any piece of information in the question.

Thanks in Advance.!!

I have tried all the ways possible but couldn't able to populate spaces in Column4 which is having datatype same as Column3 i.e, Char(50)

Comment: Is it done in a stage variable? Where are the other values from (also a dataset?)?  Have you tried trim(Column3) = '' ?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher- Yess other columns are also from same dataset file. I have tried directly in derivation tab, not in stage variable. Yeah I have tried trim(Column3)=''

Answer (score 0):

In your derivation, the `Then Column4 = ''` is a conditional statement that is asking "Is Column4 equal to empty string?" returning a Boolean value; `0` for `False` and `1` for `True`. Since `Column4` is a `CHAR(50)`, this will always be `'0'`.

Instead, you need to return spaces (`''`, `Spaces(50)`) in the `Then` portion of your derivation.

| Derivation | Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| `If Column1 = Column2 and Trim(Column3) = '' Then '' Else Column4` | Column4 |

This now will return spaces when your condition (`Column1 equals Column2 and Trim(Column3) equals empty string`) is true and the original `Column4` value when false.

Comment: Thanks.. This worked and output came as expected. Cheers..!!

Comment: I am trying to compare two columns one with Column1=Char(9) and other with Column2=Char(50). Need to do Column1=Column2, but I need only 1st 9 positions of column2 to be read to do the  equality function. Please help.!! tried trim function as well.